# Why is this regexp slow when the input line is long and has many spaces?

Tags: regex, vbscript

VBScript's Trim function only trims spaces. Sometimes I want to trim TABs as well. For this I've been using this custom trimSpTab function that is based on a regular expression.

Today I ran into a performance problem. The input consisted of rather long lines (several 1000 chars).

As it turns out
- the function is slow, only if the string is long AND contains many spaces
- the right-hand part of the regular expression is reponsible for the poor performance
- the run time seems quadratic to the line length (O(n^2))

So why is this line trimmed fast

```
"   aaa xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx bbb   "   '10000 x's
```

and this one trimmed slowly

```
"   aaa                                                 bbb   "   '10000 spaces
```

Both contain only 6 characters to be trimmed.

Can you propose a modification to my trimSpTab function?

```
Dim regex
Set regex = new regexp

' TEST 1 - executes in no time
' "   aaa XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX bbb   "
t1 = Timer
character = "X"
trimTest character
MsgBox Timer-t1 & " sec",, "with '" & character & "' in the center of the string"

' TEST 2 - executes in 1 second on my machine
' "   aaa                                                         bbb   "
t1 = Timer
character = " "
trimTest character
MsgBox Timer-t1 & " sec",, "with '" & character & "' in the center of the string"

Sub trimTest (character)
    sInput = "   aaa " & String (10000, character) & " bbb   "
    trimmed = trimSpTab (sInput)
End Sub

Function trimSpTab (byval s)
    'trims spaces & tabs
    regex.Global = True
    regex.Pattern = "^[ \t]+|[ \t]+$"  'trim left+right
    trimSpTab = regex.Replace (s, "")
End Function
```

I have tried this (with regex.Global = false) but to no avail

```
regex.Pattern = "^[ \t]+"  'trim left
s = regex.Replace (s, "")
regex.Pattern = "[ \t]+$"  'trim right
trimSpTab = regex.Replace (s, "")
```

**UPDATE**
I've come up with this alternative in the mean time. It processes a 100 million character string is less than a second.

```
Function trimSpTab (byval s)
    'trims spaces & tabs
    regex.Pattern = "^[ \t]+"
    s = strReverse (s)
    s = regex.Replace (s, "")
    s = strReverse (s)
    s = regex.Replace (s, "")
    trimSpTab = s
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution

As mentioned in the question, your current solution is to reverse the string. However, this is not necessary, since .NET regex supports `RightToLeft` matching option. For the same regex, the engine will start matching from right to left instead of default behavior of matching from left to right.

Below is sample code in C#, which I hope you can adapt to VB solution (I don't know VB enough to write sample code):

```
input = new Regex("^[ \t]+").Replace(input, "", 1)
input = new Regex("[ \t]+$", RegexOptions.RightToLeft).Replace(input, "", 1)
```

### Explanation

The long run time is due to the engine just trying to match `[ \t]+` indiscriminately in the middle of the string and end up failing when it is not an trailing blank sequence.

**The observation that the complexity is quadratic is correct.**

We know that the regex engine starts matching from index 0. If there is a match, then the next attempt starts at the end of the last match. Otherwise, the next attempt starts at the (current index + 1). (Well, to simplify things, I don't mention the case where a zero-length match is found).

Below shall illustrate the farthest attempt (some is a match, some are not) of the engine matching the regex `^[ \t]+|[ \t]+$`. `_` is used to denote space (or tab character) for clarity.

```
_____ab_______________g________
^----
     ^
      ^
       ^--------------
        ^-------------
         ^------------
          ...
                     ^
                      ^
                       ^-------
```

When there is a long sequence of spaces & tabs in the middle of the string (which will not produce a match), the engine attempts matching at every index in the long sequence of spaces & tabs. As the result, the engine ends up going through O(k<sup>2</sup>) characters on a non-matching sequence of spaces & tabs of length k.

Answer (score 0):

Your evidence proves that VBScript's RegExp implementation does not optimize for the $ anchor: It spends time (backtracking?) for each of the spaces in the middle of your test string. Without doubt, that's a fact good to know.

If this causes you real world problems, you'll have to find/write a better (R)Trim function. I came up with:

```
Function trimString(s, p)
  Dim l  : l = Len(s)
  If 0 = l Then
     trimString = s
     Exit Function
  End If
  Dim ps, pe
  For ps = 1 To l
      If 0 = Instr(p, Mid(s, ps, 1)) Then
         Exit For
      End If
  Next
  For pe = l To ps Step -1
      If 0 = Instr(p, Mid(s, pe, 1)) Then
         Exit For
      End If
  Next
  trimString = Mid(s, ps, pe - ps + 1)
End Function
```

It surely needs testing and benchmarks for long heads or tails of white space, but I hope it gets you started.